# OCaml compilation fails due to caml_oldify_local_roots

Tags: gcc, ocaml

I'm having issues building OCaml. It looks to be an issue with `libasmrun.a` but the error is quite cryptic (for me at least).

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here? I'm trying to build OCaml 4.04.0. Running Ubuntu 16.04, gcc version 4.7.2

```
roots.c: In function ‘caml_oldify_local_roots’:
roots.c:306:19: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Saved_return_address’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     retaddr = Saved_return_address(sp);
               ^
roots.c:316:46: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Callback_link’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     struct caml_context * next_context = Callback_link(sp);ng
                                          ^
roots.c:316:46: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
roots.c: In function ‘caml_do_local_roots’:
roots.c:492:46: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     struct caml_context * next_context = Callback_link(sp);
                                          ^
backtrace_prim.c: In function ‘caml_next_frame_descriptor’:
backtrace_prim.c:55:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Saved_return_address’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   *pc = Saved_return_address(*sp);
         ^
backtrace_prim.c:63:44: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Callback_link’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   struct caml_context * next_context = Callback_link(*sp);
                                        ^
backtrace_prim.c:63:44: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
make[4]: *** No rule to make target 'none.o', needed by 'libasmrun.a'. Stop.
make[3]: *** [makeruntimeopt] Error 2
make[2]: *** [opt-core] Error 2
make[1]: *** [opt.opt] Error 2
make: *** [world.opt] Error 2
```

Comment: Running Ubuntu 16.04, gcc version 4.7.2

Comment: The actual here seems to be **No rule to make target 'none.o', needed by 'libasmrun.a'.**. The others are just warnings. No make target might indicate an issue with the `./configure` perhaps (I don't really know much about building OCaml, or make and autotools and such for that matter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you do not need to build the OCaml compiler from sources, as you can always get the latest version from OPAM, that will download, build and install it for you. However, if you really need it, then follow these steps:

```
./configure
make world 
sudo make install
```

Make sure, that every step succeeds. I.e., `echo $?` shows `0` after each command.

The `configure` script accepts lots of interesting options, the `-prefix` option is the most important to learn. For the detailed installation and building, instructions look at the `INSTALL.adoc` file, located in the top-level directory of the source tree.

Concerning the missing `none.o`. The `none.o` is a placeholder module for the backend implementation, that is used if the native code generation is not supported for the target platform. Thus if you see that error, then it means, that you can't do `make world.opt` as there is no native code compiler for your architecture.

You still may install the OCaml system with the bytecode only compiler on any architecture that has a decent C compiler. If you are using OPAM then there is a special compiler switch for that

```
opam switch 4.04.0+bytecode-only
```

or, if you are initializing OPAM

```
opam init --comp=4.04.0+bytecode-only
```

Comment: This is actually the output from OPAM which should do as you've described

Comment: Then it means, that your architecture is not supported.

Comment: This worked. Oddly my architecture should be supported according to docs: Linux xxx 4.6.5-x86_64-xxxx71 #2 SMP Fri Jul 29 16:16:25 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yep, x86 is definitely supported, you should submit a bug report to https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/issues